# Spring MVC 4 frammework

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web

I build a web project based on Spring MVC 4 and i don't know why it does not work as expected. I can't found answer for this problem. Sorry if this is duplicated question :(. I've tried a lot of ways.

[My project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6WTW.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6BaE.png)

Web.xml

```
<display-name>SpringBaSic</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="springapp.web.controller" />
```

HelloController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
        return "hello.jsp";     
    }
}
```

hello.jsp

```
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>MVC Sping 4</h1>
   <p>Hello: <b>${message}</b></p>
</body>
```

Comment: What error do you get? Some snap shots/description of the error might help here.

Comment: view Result image, pls

Comment: @NewbieJava it's usually encouraged to post everything on your question instead of having external links

Comment: Put this line `<%@ page isELIgnored ="false" %>` in `hello.jsp`. Also what do you get if written as `${requestScope}`?

Comment: I've tried but ineffective. When i written ${requestScope}, hello.jsp show: {}

Answer (score 1):

Change your controller with below code:

```
            @Controller
            public class HelloController {  

             @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
             public ModelAndView printHello() {  
                    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
                    model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");  
                    model.setViewName("hello"); //your jsp page name
                    return model;     
                }
            }
```

Comment: try this link if u have not tried before or if u have already tried ignore it- http://crunchify.com/simplest-spring-mvc-hello-world-example-tutorial-spring-model-view-controller-tips/